# Git submodule does not checkout properly

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two local copies of a git repositiry with submodules. Let's call them `WORKING` and `BUILD`. I use `WORKING` to write my code and commit changes. `BUILD` has `WORKING` set as a remote (all submodules of `BUILD` pointy to corresponding submodules in `WORKING`). I pull changes from `WORKING` into `BUILD` and build my code in that tree.

Recently I am experiencing a problem with `BUILD` and I am looking for a solution other than deleting `BUILD` and checking out the code from the upstream repo. When I checkout my branch in one particular submodule in `BUILD` files on the filesystem do not get updated. In other words I am on my branch (according to `git status`), I can see commits that I made on my branch (with `git log`) and I can even see what changes I made in those commits (with `git diff master`), but files on the disk don't contain any of these changes. They are the same as on `master` branch. How can I diagnose the cause of this problem?

EDIT: I noticed that when I checkout my branch contents of files on disk corresponds to master, while when I checkout master contents of files corresponds to my branch. This does not happen in `WORKING`, only in `BUILD`.

Comment: What is the 'upstream repo'? WORKING? What is 'your branch' in a submodule of BUILD, and how do you check it out?

Comment: Did you experience any errors during the checkout? A common one would be `unable to unlink <file>` or something like that.

What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: Oznerol256: I don't get any kind of errors.

Comment: SzG: origin points to a repo on remote server. I have my-branch in main repo and in the submodule. I check them out by first checking out my-branch in the submodule and then by checking it out in the main repo (I use a script to do that). I think that problems began when I started to check out branch submodule before main repo. I no reverted to checking out branch in main repo before submodule but I don't know yet if this solves the problem.